# How to change Table Widget background color in PYQT5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, pyqt4, pyqt6

I am trying to change the background of a table widget column and row in pyqt5 designer but I don't see any option. I tried adding a background color in stylesheet but still it doesn't change the color for row and column

[image: I want to change the background color for row and column]

I would like to change the background color for row and column for table widget in pyqt5 designer or code

Comment: Per-item styling is not supported in Qt, including row or column based. If you want to do that, you need to use a custom item delegate.

Comment: no, i don't care about the item color inside, all I want to change the color of the outside table. In the picture you can see the arrows I have pointed, I would like to change the color for those only. NOT the content inside.

Comment: Those are the *headers*. If you want to change the background of row/column headers in Designer, then just double click the table, select the header row or column in the respective tab, click the "Properties" button and change the "background" property of those items.

Comment: Yes I have tried that but when i try to preview it doesn't show the color I choose. I just don't change at all. why is that

Comment: Two possibilities: 1. you used a stylesheet that overrides the default behavior (ensure that you're using proper [selectors](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html) and remember that setting color properties for the table or the header will completely *ignore* the backgroundrole; 2. it depends on the system style (unfortunately, you didn't say what OS you're using); in that case, set the style for the header (or the view) by code with the default "Fusion" style, for instance: `self.table.horizontalHeader().setStyle(QStyleFactory.create('fusion'))`